# Google Tag Manager throwing 406 from mod security rules?

Tags: google-tag-manager, mod-security

Looking to change everything over to Google Tag Manager... tried it out this afternoon and found that any pages with the script throw a 406 error and in turn the rest of the site cannot be accessed either (regardless if the tag is present on them or not) because of that.

It appears that mod security is the culprit.  Here is an example entry :

```
2015-01-07 20:06:03 www.​test.​com 111.111.111.111 CRITICAL 406 

 ✏ 959901: SQL​ Injection​ Attack  

 Hide   

  GET /​support​/​contact​.​php
```

... and this could be related as well.  The whole reason I decided to use Google Tag Manager in the first place is Google Adwords kept reporting glcid errors, however, this was from using the normal script and not tag manager :

```
2014-12-31 16:09:09 www.​test.com 222.222.222.222 CRITICAL 501 

 ✏ 959006: System​ Command​ Injection  

 Hide   

  GET /​?​gclid​=​CO2jqKWY8cICFVgWjgod​LZ8AzA
```

I would assume this is a common problem since most hosts have mod security enabled... what is the solution here if any?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up removing this rule for the domain it was causing problems.

For my server this required the following :

create file :

```
“/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/username/domain.com" with vhost.conf in it
```

add to file :

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>

SecRuleRemoveById give_ruleID_here

</IfModule>
```

run :

```
/scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --user=username
```